# How to find out if more than one column is filtered

Tags: dax, filtering, powerbi-desktop

Let's assume I have a table called `Campaigns` and `RangeCampaigns`, I have written one DAX code which gets a total using that `Campaigns` table and another one getting a total from the `RangeCampaigns` table.

What I want to do is, if the `Campaign slicer` has been filtered on its own it should show `Measure 1`, however, if its not filtered (or it's filtered alongside any other filter) it should show `Measure 2`

[image]

Example:
If Campaign and range_group were filtered it should return the `Measure 2 value (Total Avg Bays)`

Current Code:

```
testCode = 
IF ( ISFILTERED('Campaign Table'[campaign]) = TRUE(),
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( range_plans, range_plans[branch] ,range_plans[range_name], range_plans[number_bays]),
        range_plans[number_bays]
    ),
    [Total Avg Bays])
```

Issue:

When range_group is filtered it does not change, but I don't want to explicitly check if that slicer is filtered I want to dynamically check if any other column is being filtered to determine which value to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
testCode = 
  var onlyCampaignFiltered =
    ISFILTERED('Campaign Table'[campaign]) &&
    NOT CALCULATE(ISCROSSFILTERED('range_plans'), REMOVEFILTERS('Campaign Table'[campaign]) )

  RETURN IF(onlyCampaignFiltered,
    SUMX (
      SUMMARIZE ( range_plans, range_plans[branch] ,range_plans[range_name], range_plans[number_bays]),
      range_plans[number_bays]
    ),
    [Total Avg Bays]
  )
```